# open source textual preprocessor recommendation (GPL compatible)

Tags: open-source, text-processing

I am seeking for some open source (GPLv3+ friendly and compatible) textual preprocessor for Linux (for the [RefPerSys](https://github.com/RefPerSys/RefPerSys/) inference engine project)

The need is to generate an input to [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/).

FYI, [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html) is too low level; and [GPP](https://github.com/logological/gpp/) is too general.

Probably, a`cpp` variant using some other character than `#` for directives could fit. (e.g. `@define` instead of `#define`)